# Add double tap to UICollectionView; require single tap to fail

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

With a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792661/how-to-detect-double-taps-on-cells-in-a-uicollectionview), I am trying to add a double tap gesture recognizer to my `UICollectionView` instance.

I need to prevent the default single tap from calling the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`.

In order to achieve this I implement the code [straight from Apple's *Collection View Programming Guide* (Listing 4-2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/IncorporatingGestureSupport/IncorporatingGestureSupport.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH4-SW5):

> ```
> UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
> NSArray* recognizers = [self.collectionView gestureRecognizers];
>
> // Make the default gesture recognizer wait until the custom one fails.
> for (UIGestureRecognizer* aRecognizer in recognizers) {
>    if ([aRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
>       [aRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapGesture];
> }
>
> // Now add the gesture recognizer to the collection view.
> tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
> [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
> ```

This code does not work as expected: `tapGesture` fires on a double tap but the default single tap is not prevented and the delegate's `didSelect...` method is still called.

Stepping through in the debugger reveals that the if condition, `[aRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]`, never evaluates to true and so the failure-requirement on the new `tapGesture` is not being established.

Running this debugger command each time through the for-loop:

```
po (void)NSLog(@"%@",(NSString *)NSStringFromClass([aRecognizer class]))
```

reveals that the default gesture recognizers are (indeed) not `UITapGestureRecognizer` instances.

Instead they are private classes [`UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer.h) and [`UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer.h).

First, I can't use these explicitly without breaking the rules about Private API. Second, attaching to the `UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer` via `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` doesn't appear to provide the desired behaviour anyway — i.e. the delegate's `didSelect...` is still called.

How can I work with `UICollectionView`'s default gesture recognizers to add a double tap to the collection view and prevent the default single tap from also firing the delegate's `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't not implementing `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` enough?

Comment: @cahn: Afraid not — I need the double tap in addition to the standard behaviour.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792661/how-to-detect-double-taps-on-cells-in-a-uicollectionview) seems to solve the same issue you're having. Does it work?

Comment: @AshFurrow: I'm afraid not — My double tap IS working but I (too) CAN'T stop didSelect... getting called as well. The suggestion about shouldSelect... and shouldDeselect... looks interesting but the "erm..., this isn't right" comment leaves me a little unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to not implement collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath but to implement two gesture recognizers.

```
    self.doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processDoubleTap:)];
    [_doubleTapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [_doubleTapGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];   

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_doubleTapGesture];

    self.singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processSingleTap:)];
    [_singleTapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [_singleTapGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [_singleTapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_doubleTapGesture];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_singleTapGesture];
```

This way I can handle single and double taps. The only gotcha I can see is that the cell is selected on doubleTaps but if this bothers you can you handle it in your two selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems this is the way to go.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution because of following reasons:
1) You may have existing code, that already uses selection
2) You may want selection in the future
3) gestureRecognizers meant to be used in any views and this views can have all different logic for handling touch events.
Using delaysTouchesBegan/Ended is much more scalable solution. ( See Szilto's answer)

Comment: I agree now, but back in '13 I'm pretty sure I tried that and never got it to work. I could be wrong obviously but I like Sz'z code also.

Comment: Single tap gesture can be used instead of collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath only in case the selection is fast. In case the user is touching the cell for a while and then release the finger, the didSelectItemAtIndexPath will be called but not your tap gesture so it might frustrate some users

Answer (score 4):

I use the following to register a UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];
singleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; // number of taps required
singleTapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; // number of finger touches required
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
```

By setting `delaysTouchesBegan` to `YES` the custom gesture recognizer gets priority over the default collection view tap listeners by delaying the registering of other touch events. Alternatively, you can set cancel touch recognition altogether by setting the `cancelsTouchesInView` to `YES`.

The gesture is than handled by the following function:

```
- (void)handleSingleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.collectionsView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionsView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];

        if (indexPath) {
            NSLog(@"Cell view was tapped.");
            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionsView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            // Do something.                
        }
    }
    else{
        // Handle other UIGestureRecognizerState's
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly without changing existing code much, .delyaTouchesBegan is the way to go.